# Devise update user password without password_confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I want to update users password without password_confirmation in devise. In case password field is blank - password don't change. How could I do this with devise?
Maybe use required_password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not necessary to enter, password:

```
  def password_required?
    !persisted? || !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
  end
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb

string - 49

Comment: Can I ask what the answer is here? Not sure how to interpret this

Answer (score 1):

Look at the devise wiki https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Comment: Thanks, but in a different way. When I change the password, I don't need to confirm this a second time (password_confirmation) but the current password is needed.

Answer (score 0):

latest rails 6 solution:

```
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update(params)
  end
```

in your registrations_controller.rb file